# How to apply the ng-class based attributes and click in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

We need to change the CSS class based on the data-toggle attributes and on user click. We already can change the class based on user click events.

How can I change the class on both user click and based on the data-toggle attributes?

HTML:

```
<a ng-click="iconChange('FF'+$index)" 
   href="#" data-toggle="collapse">
   <span  title="{{idx}}" 
          ng-class="{'glyphicon1 down': FF{{$index}}, 'glyphicon1 right': !FF{{$index}} }" && 
          ng-attr-data-toggle="{{ collapse ? true : false }}">
     </span>
 </a>
```

JS:

```
$scope.iconChange = function(idx){
                            $scope[idx] = !$scope[idx];
                        };
```

Comment: howo is the data-toggle attribute being set?

Comment: i need to change class using attribute value not like data-toggle

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ui-boostrap collapse](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse) directive to toggle whether the item is collapsed.

I believe your `ng-class` attribute in your template could be improved. Try something like the following.

```
<a ng-click="iconChange($index)" 
   href="#">
   <span  title="{{idx}}" class="glyphicon1"
          ng-class="{down: showDown[$index], right: !showDown[$index] }"
     </span>
 </a>
 <div uib-collapse="showDown[$index]">...</div>
```

And then your controller should include

```
// Initialize object
$scope.showDown = {};

$scope.iconChange = function(idx){
    $scope.showDown[idx] = !$scope.showDown[idx];
}
```

This will probably be an either property to set than the interpolated variable name.

Comment: i need to change class using attribute value not like data-toggle

Comment: How is that attribute value being set?

Comment: Any ways change ng-class based on element attribute like true or false

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand where the true or false value is coming from. I've added a reference to the ui-bootstrap project which may help you with collapsing sections.

Comment: You have any idea regarding toggle class using attribute value

Comment: It will be hard to get the attribute value from the HTML without writing a special directive. However, if the attribute value is an Angular expression you can use that to set your class flag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111556/discussion-between-chic-and-codeman).